# Why is the Pygame .blit() function not working?

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I want to blit the enemy to the screen but the
`.blit()` in `enemy()` is not working. I tried printing the `enemies` list and it is being appended but the it still isn't blit the enemy to the screen. also I am not getting any error

Heres my code

```
def enemy(enemies):
    enemy = pygame.Rect(width//2, height//2, 100, 100)
    enemies.append(enemy)
    for enemy in enemies:
        window.blit(enemy_transform, enemy)
        enemy.x -= enemy_vel

def main():
    running = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    player = pygame.Rect(50, height//2 - 50, 150, 150)

    enemies = []

    while running:
        clock.tick(60)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
                pygame.quit
                sys.exit

        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        player_movement(player, keys_pressed)
        draw_window(player)
        enemy(enemies)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and trace through the logic of your program. Hint: What is the purpose of `pygame.display.update()`? Each time through the loop, at what point does that call happen? Specifically: do the enemies get drawn before the call, or after? Do you see why that causes a problem?

Comment: How the question "sounds" doesn't matter (neither does your level of expertise). What matters is asking the question to the site standards, in accordance with the purpose of the site. Please keep in mind that this is *not a discussion forum, but a Q&A repository*; when you ask a question here, it should ideally not be with the mindset "I need help with this problem", but instead "I noticed that Stack Overflow is missing this question and answer pair". The best questions are those that help *the next person* solve a problem by using a search engine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question it should have no more code than the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem by copy-pasting, a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to draw the enemies in the application loop. Create the enemies before the application loop, move them in the application loop and draw them in `draw_window`.

Make sure that functions and variables have different names. In your code, you use the name `enemy` for a function and a variable. Use different names at this point. e.g.:

```py
def draw_window(player, enemies):
    window.blit(background, (0, 0))
    for enemy in enemies:
        window.blit(enemy_transform, enemy)
    window.blit(player_transform, player)
    pygame.display.update()

def move_enemies(enemies):
    for enemy_rect in enemies:
        enemy_rect.x -= enemy_vel
```

```py
def main():
    running = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    player = pygame.Rect(50, height//2 - 50, 150, 150)

    enemies = []
    enemy_rect = pygame.Rect(width//2, height//2, 100, 100)
    enemies.append(enemy_rect)

    while running:
        clock.tick(60)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        player_movement(player, keys_pressed)
        move_enemies(enemies)
        
        draw_window(player, enemies)

    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
```